# how to convert json string column to integer in where query postgres in laravel

Tags: json, laravel, postgresql

I have `$services = CitizenService::with('service_status');`
and I will do filter by json data 
`$services=$services->where('data->unikal_id', '>=', 1)->where('data->unikal_id', '<=', 10);`

'data->unikal_id' is string so it does not check for int. I need to switch data->unikal_id to int type

Comment: this is a wrong query ```$services=$services->where('data->unikal_id', '>=', 1)->where('data->unikal_id', '<=', 10);``` you have to do it like this ```$services=$services->where('unikal_id', '>=', 1)->where('unikal_id', '<=', 10);```

Comment: this data is json and unikal_id inside in data column type jsonb